# Automate arranging files into folders based on part of file name?

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript, automator

Looking to quickly arrange multiple thousands of files on my iMac into subfolders with the folder name being based on the characters before the first dash of file name (the title of the series). Not experienced in terminal really.

Example file names:

```
40 Olifanten - 01 - Florrie, Met De Feeënvingers.cbz
40 Olifanten - 02 - Maggie, Die Door Muren Loopt.cbz
40 Olifanten - 03 - Dorothy, De Gaatjesmaakster.cbz
Achilles - 01 - De Schone Helena.cbz
Achilles - 02 - Uit Liefde Voor Patroclus.cbz
Adler De Tweekoppige Adelaar - 01 - Een Leugentje Om Bestwil.cbz
Adler De Tweekoppige Adelaar - 02 - De Keuze Van Het Kwaad.cbz
Adler De Tweekoppige Adelaar - 03 - Ik Ben Wie Ik Ben.cbz
```

The file structure is always the same i.e., title of the series - episode # - episode name.cbz and I would like a script to automatically create folders with the title of the series as the folder name and move the corresponding files into these folders for instance

```
folder: 40 Olifanten
    40 Olifanten - 01 - Florrie, Met De Feeënvingers.cbz
    40 Olifanten - 02 - Maggie, Die Door Muren Loopt.cbz
    40 Olifanten - 03 - Dorothy, De Gaatjesmaakster.cbz
folder: Achilles
    Achilles - 01 - De Schone Helena.cbz
    Achilles - 02 - Uit Liefde Voor Patroclus.cbz
folder: Adler De Tweekoppige Adelaar
    Adler De Tweekoppige Adelaar - 01 - Een Leugentje Om Bestwil.cbz
    Adler De Tweekoppige Adelaar - 02 - De Keuze Van Het Kwaad.cbz
    Adler De Tweekoppige Adelaar - 03 - Ik Ben Wie Ik Ben.cbz
```

Any help would be enormously appreciated!

Comment: There are quite a few rather similar questions linked in the "Related" section at right (or below in case you access the site on a mobile device). What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: @MateusRibeiro Several versions of the simple script required to solve the problem above are already on the site. As for any other question we expect askers to look for suitable answers and try them first.

Comment: @nohillside I don't think you understand how hard is to adapt a "simple" script for someone who is not a professional coder. Also many people have no experience creating Quick Actions. You are just disregarding his issue in the name of the pride of this pretentious, arrogant community. I have the script ready, all I need is for you to unblock the question, so I can improve my tiny reputation, the guy will have an easyer life and many people in the future could benefit from another angle to this problem. Also, this is not "off-topic" at all. You may state it is repeated, which I disagree.

Comment: @MateusRibeiro The detailed reason for the hold is „ Questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.“ (which is visible to the OP).

Comment: In general we are not a script-writing service (there are professionals doing this for a living) and expect at least some basic attempt by the OP to solve the problem. The question indicates that they are not very used to Terminal, but what does this mean? Did they try some solutions and didn’t get them to work; are they looking for pointers to get started (them „Use bash and find, and read the man pages“ might be the answer), or do they just want to get the job done? Currently we can only guess :-)

Comment: @MateusRibeiro Anyway, looking forward to your solution.